Can wormhole inside a black hole become an escape?
I did not major in Physics so not sure if this is a proper question; but according to some Google search there do exist papers discussing wormhole inside black hole like this, which I am not able to comprehend and thus not sure if it directly answered this question.
My question is, if a wormhole can be created within a black hole, is it possible that its exit somehow escape the black hole outside the event horizon, or does there exist some physics laws that restrict the wormhole exit to remain inside the event horizon of the same black hole?
Second, if it's possible, would this become a loop to destroy the black hole or the wormhole itself, or just some of the black hole mass would leak outside the event horizon?

Your question is based on a popular view that a black hole is a sphere of the horizon with space inside. This is incorrect. The horizon essentially is a temporal tunnel to beyond the infinite future of the universe. In a sense, roughly speaking, a black hole is filled with time, not space. Thus your question can be rephrased this way: If tomorrow I could create a wormhole, then could I escape from tomorrow back to today (which by then would be yesterday)?
